# How and where is sigreturn() called, when a signal is handled (UNIX/Linux)

Tags: linux, signals

I try to get a deep understanding of how signals work in Linux. I can't figure out where `sigreturn()` is called exactly. From the manpage I know, that it is called after the "signal trampoline", which is the specified callback. Does the libc-implementation add the `sigreturn()`-call after the trampoline is done?

Minimal code example:

```c
int main() {
    // Interrupt from keyboard; Ctrl+C
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    return 0;
}


static void sig_handler(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
       
    }
}
```

I looked into the source code of the musl libc, but couldn't find helpful insights about how and where `sigreturn()` gets called.

Comment: Depending on architecture, on Linux the signal trampoline code is either loaded as part of the [vdso](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) or lives somewhere in libc.

Comment: And the trampoline makes the sigreturn call.